# How to use dynamic key in multidimensional json in v-model with vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble selecting the options of a select with the start and end data inside the dynamic keys of the following multidimensional json:

```
rowsels: {"days":{"mon":{"start":"08:00","end":"18:00"},"tue":{"start":"09:00","end":"15:00"},"fou":{"start":"10:00","end":"19:00"},"fif":{"start":"15:00","end":"17:00"},"fri":{"start":"08:00","end":"18:00"},"sat":{"start":"24hours","end":"00:00"},"sun":{"start":"closed","end":"00:00"}},"obs":"We do not serve on weekends and holidays. Vacation in December until February."};
```

I needed to do something like this:

```
v-model="rowsels.days.{{ index }}.start"
v-model="rowsels.days.{{ index }}.end"
```

I've tried it in many other ways and nothing has worked out until now.

Can someone help me? ♥

**Here is the complete code I'm trying to do:**

```js
new Vue({
        el: "#timesvue",
        data: {
           rowsels: {"days":{"mon":{"start":"08:00","end":"18:00"},"tue":{"start":"09:00","end":"15:00"},"fou":{"start":"10:00","end":"19:00"},"fif":{"start":"15:00","end":"17:00"},"fri":{"start":"08:00","end":"18:00"},"sat":{"start":"24hours","end":"00:00"},"sun":{"start":"closed","end":"00:00"}},"obs":"We do not serve on weekends and holidays. Vacation in December until February."},
           rows: {"mon":"Monday","tue":"Tuesday","fou":"Fourth","fif":"Fifth","fri":"Friday","sat":"Saturday","sun":"Sunday"}
        }
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="timesvue">
 <div class="form-group" v-for="(row, index) in rows">
  <div class="col-md-2">{{ row }}</div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <select v-bind:name="'time[days]['+index+'][start]'" 
                v-model="rowsels.days.{{ index }}.start">

    <option value="closed">Closed</option>
    <option value="24hours">24 hours</option>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
    <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
    <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
    <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
    <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
    <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
    <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
    <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
    <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
    <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
    <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
    <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
    <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
    <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
    <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
    <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
    <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
    <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
    <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
    <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
    <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
    <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
    <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
    <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
    <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
    <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
    <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
    <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
    <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
    <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
    <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
   </select>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <select v-bind:name="'time[days]['+index+'][end]'"
             v-model="rowsels.days.{{ index }}.end">

    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
    <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
    <option value="02:30">02:30</option>
    <option value="03:00">03:00</option>
    <option value="03:30">03:30</option>
    <option value="04:00">04:00</option>
    <option value="04:30">04:30</option>
    <option value="05:00">05:00</option>
    <option value="05:30">05:30</option>
    <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
    <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
    <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
    <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
    <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
    <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
    <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
    <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
    <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
    <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
    <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
    <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
    <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
    <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
    <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
    <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
    <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
    <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
    <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
    <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
    <option value="20:30">20:30</option>
    <option value="21:00">21:00</option>
    <option value="21:30">21:30</option>
    <option value="22:00">22:00</option>
    <option value="22:30">22:30</option>
    <option value="23:00">23:00</option>
    <option value="23:30">23:30</option>
   </select> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]` instead of `{{}}`; mustache (`{{}}`) is used for text interpolation, and [it cannot be used inside HTML attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html), for which you need to use javascript expressions:

```
v-model="rowsels.days[index].start"
v-model="rowsels.days[index].end"
```

Comment: The way you said this is correct, I was using a dot before [ -> `.days.[index] ` . Thank you so much for helping me.